# How to use Swift generics to pass a type and return an object as that type?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift

I'm writing a function that, given a type, simply unarchives an object from the disk and returns it as that type. This is what it looks like:

```
public class func objectWithFileName<T>(fileName: String, inFolder folder: NSSearchPathDirectory) -> T? {
    // Build an NSURL var called fileURL based on the fileName and folder.
    // ...

    // If any object was found
    if let object: AnyObject = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(fileURL.path!) {
        // Attempt to return the object as an object of type T.
        if let typedObject = object as? T {
            return typedObject
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

The planned way of consuming the function is this, and it doesn't work (I'm getting "Cannot specialize a non-generic definition"):

```
if let user = MQFileManager.objectWithFileName<User>("User", inFolder: .DocumentDirectory) {

}
```

How can I pull this off correctly?

Comment: Note: the body of your function is simplified to `return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(fileURL.path!) as? T`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you specify the type of the variable the return value is assigned to, type inference can do the rest. So if you have a `User` type, simply invoke the function as follows:

```
if let user: User = MQFileManager.objectWithFileName("User", inFolder: .DocumentDirectory) {

}
```

Since the `user` variable is of `User` type, the compiler can infer the `T` generic to be of `User` type

Answer (score 2):

You need pass the type into the arguments

```
public class func objectWithFileName<T>(fileName: String, inFolder folder: NSSearchPathDirectory, type:T.Type) -> T? {
    // Your function detail
}
```

Then using it like this

```
MQFileManager.objectWithFileName("User", inFolder: .DocumentDirectory, type:User.self)
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a generic class to help me manager file in Swift, I believe this can help you with your question.

It is my load method

```
static func loadFile<T:TCFileData>(#name:String, classType:T.Type)->T!
{
    var data:T?;
    
    if(hasFile(name: name))
    {
        if let rawData = NSData(contentsOfFile: getPath(name) as String) {
            var object: AnyObject? = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(rawData);
            data = object as? T;
        }
    }
    
    return data;
}

static func loadFile<T:TCFileData>(classType:T.Type)->T!
{
    return loadFile(name: getFileName(classType), classType:classType);
}
```

I upload this code to [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Tavernari/TavernarisCode/blob/master/TCFile.swift), there has complete class

### Implementation

With this class, I called TCFile, you can implement this way to save many class in your drive

```
 //TCFileData is a "protocol" to save with TCFile
 class MySaveClass:TCFileData
 {
   //implement your class with NSCode and NSCoding pattern
 }

 TCFile.save(name:"someId", object: MySaveClass());
 let mySaveClass = TCFile.loadFile(name:"someId", classType: MySaveClass.self);
```

or other simple mode, this way is recommended in case you save the same object all time, you don't need many object from this object.

```
 let mySaveClass = MySaveClass()
 TCFile.save(mySaveClass)
 let mySaveClassFromDisc = TCFile.loadFile(MySaveClass.self)
```